# Static variable variables in PHP

Tags: variables, static

Is it possible to make variable variables static in PHP? The thing I'm storing in the variables are links to classes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class Foo {
   public static $bar = 'test';
}

echo Foo::$bar;

function bar() {
    static $a = 1;

    return $a++;
}

echo bar();
echo bar();
?>
```

Or i don't get it.

Comment: http://talks.php.net/show/veracruz/50 - you might want to check that link out to find out what variable variables is

Comment: Use `$static_array[$var] = $value;` instead of `$$var = $value;`